# Как получить доступ к sdram на плате?

Tags: память, микроконтроллеры, прошивка

Как залить прошивку bmc в sdram на плате ?

Или как получить доступ к sdram распаянной на плате ?

Чип BMC : aspeed ast2500

sdram : NT5CC128M161P-DI

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. BMC как правило имеет полный доступ к перефирии, включая процессорную память. Проблема в том, что кто-то должен её инициализировать, запустить регенерацию и другие вещи. У x86, к примеру, это делается специальным блобом (FSP), который выполняется загрузчиком или другим начальным кодом. В случае же BMC я думаю, что вам самим как-то нужно это всё делать.